# How to use a Neural Network for face detection?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, neural-network, theano

I'm trying to build a face detection system using a neural network written in theano. I am a bit confused as to what should be the expected output against which i would have to calculate the crossentropy. I don't want to know whether the face is present or not, i need to highlight the face in an image (find the location of the face). The size of the images is constant. But the size of the faces in the image is not. How do i go about that? Also, my webcam currently captures 480x640 images. Creating that number of neurons in the input layer would be very heavy on the system, how do i compress the images without losing any features?

Answer (score 3):

There are many possible solutions, one of the easiest ones is to perform a sliding window search and ask a network "is there a face in this part of an image?" - and this is quite "standard" approach. In particular, you do it hierarchicaly - split image into 9 overlapping squares (I assume the image is square) and ask in each of them "is there a face in it?" by rescaling it to your network input. Next you again split the one answering "yes" into 9 squares and repeat. This way you can find face kind fast. Another would be to perform supervised segmentation where you try to predict which part of image (pixels/superpixels) belong to face and which do not. This is not exhaustive list, but should give you general idea how to proceed.

> how do i compress the images without losing any features?

You do not. It is not possible. You will always lose some data when downscaling (lossless compression exists but it destroys structure, thus making classification extremely hard).

Comment: @moose this is exactly what is written in the answer, read carefully the last sentence **(loseless compression exist but it destroys structure, thus making classification extremely hard)**

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I've deleted my comment.

Answer (score -1):

You should first create a training set from the images received through the web-cam. The training set must contain face and non-face images (such as apple, car and ...). For better generalization you may use some off-the-shelve data sets. After you trained the network on the images you can use the network to classify unseen images.

This approach is suitable if your goal is to only detect whether an image contains a face. However, if you want to identify faces (e.g. this face belongs to John and not other people) you need to train the network with the images of the people you want to do identification for. The number of classes in such network is equivalent to the number of distinct people.

Comment: OP is asking about **detecting the location of the face**, not about recognizing if something is a face/is someones face.

Comment: @lejlot well in any face detection system the first step is to detect the network to find **faces** in the images fed to it! then the hidden nodes of the network could help determining where the face is in an image. For the latter part, I was just trying to give some more information!